# Which one is correct PayPal API code to use for Payment by Credit/Debit card?

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on eCommerce application which requires PayPal payment gateway to get payments from customer via Credit/Debit Card. I have gone thru all PayPal API types available on developer site, but I could not find the one which I require. Can anyone help me to get out of this confusion of which one is correct API code to use.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@companyname.com">

        <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

        <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Camera">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="CAM0548">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.0">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

        <!-- Specify URLs -->
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/paypal/cancel.php'>
        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/paypal/success.php'>


        <!-- Display the payment button. -->
        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

    </form>
```

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try Paypal Express Checkout and this is batter way.

See the demo: https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/navigation?device=desktop&page=merchantHome

Download demo code: https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/download?capability=checkOutWithPaypal&lang=PHP

Comment: Sorry but It is asking to log in to PayPal account instead of credit/debit card detail. Is there any restrictions for Indian country or what?

Comment: @NileshChauhan, paypal express checkout provide both options.

Comment: @NileshChauhan, if it is helpful, don't forget to rate this.

Comment: But I don't see option for payment via credit/debit. 
Is there any changes required to perform in the Demo Code link you shared above ?

Answer (score 1):

classic integration by paypal with the html form as below. Reference : [Paypal html form basics](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Memorex 256MB Memory Stick">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="MEM32507725">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3">
  <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

  <!-- Enable override of buyers's address stored with PayPal . -->
  <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
  <!-- Set variables that override the address stored with PayPal. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="345 Lark Ave">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="San Jose">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="CA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="95121">
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
  <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

and use an ipn listener for updating payments on your server as mentioned in paypal docs [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)

Comment: Do I need to mention item name and price in this form ? Because there can be more than 1 items during checkout process. 

And in this code what happens is they ask to create paypal account instead of asking just card number, expiry date and CVV number. I do not want customer to create account for making payment. Ho can I avoid that?

Comment: Yes you need to add items and multiple items can be added. Please refer to the link in answer. For checkout without account here is a helpful link https://help.shopify.com/manual/payment-settings/paypal/let-customers-pay-without-account